# Find matching characters in two strings with same and different positions

Tags: python, string, for-loop, if-statement

I want to return a score for if a character in the user's guess is the same as a character in the substring of the word that they're guessing. There are different scores for vowels and consonants being guessed and whether they are in the correct positions or not.

So for example:

```
# vowel in wrong index
>>> def compute_value_for_guess('aecdio', 3, 4, 'ix')
5
# vowel in correct index
>>> def compute_value_for_guess('aecdio', 3, 4, 'xi')
14
# multiple matches
>>> def compute_value_for_guess('aecdio', 1, 4, 'cedi')
36
```

This is my attempt so far:

```
VOWELS = "aeiou"
CONSONANTS = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"

def compute_value_for_guess(word, start_index, end_index, guess):
    """
    word(str): word being guessed
    start_index, end_index(int): substring of word from start_index up to and including 
    end_index
    guess(str): user's guess of letters in substring
    """
    score = 0
    for ia in range(len(word[start_index:end_index+1])):
        for ib in range(len(guess)):
            if word[ia] in VOWELS and guess[ib] in VOWELS:
                if guess[ib] in word[start_index:end_index+1]:
                    if ia == ib:
                        score += 14
                    elif ia != ib:
                        score += 5
                else:
                    score += 0
            elif word[ia] in CONSONANTS and guess[ib] in CONSONANTS:
                    if guess[ib] in word[start_index:end_index+1]:
                        if ia == ib:
                            score += 12
                        elif ia != ib:
                            score += 5
                    else:
                        score += 0
```

I'm getting some values for vowels but they are not correct and it keeps returning `0` for consonants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does (in my opinion) one unnecessary loop over the word being guessed and looks overly complicated.

I poste here my suggestion of an improved code:

```
VOWELS = "aeiou"
CONSONANTS = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"

def compute_value_for_guess(word, start_index, end_index, guess):
    """
    word(str): word being guessed
    start_index, end_index(int): substring of word from start_index up to and including 
    end_index
    guess(str): user's guess of letters in substring
    """
    score = 0
    substring = word[start_index:end_index+1]
    print (substring)
    for ib in range(len(guess)):
        # check if the char is in the substring
        if guess[ib] in substring:
            # increase score depending on position and vowel/consonant
            if substring[ib] != guess[ib]:
                score += 5
            elif guess[ib] in VOWELS:
                score += 14
            else:
                score += 12

    # return the score!
    return score
```